# A good way to create a sequence of pairs in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence of random 2D points in R using runif. What is a good way to do that?

This is my current implementation(does not work)

```
getpoints <- function(n)
  {
    t <- 1:n;
    for (i in 1:n)
      {
        t[i] <- runif(2,-1,1)
      }
    return (t)
  }
```

Comment: ALWAYS explain "does not work". Show either error messages, or why what happens isn't what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 n <- 5
 cbind(runif(n,-1,1),runif(n,-1,1))
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.68434317 -0.7772889
[2,] -0.91200792 -0.6408075
[3,] -0.01888610  0.7350491
[4,]  0.01782097  0.9674700
[5,] -0.56707264 -0.9991566
```

Answer (score 9):

```
n <- 200
o <- matrix(runif(2*n, min = -1, max = 1), ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Upvote because one call to `runif` is most likely to be better than two.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the numerous answers you have here. This one, like @Arun's is easily able to handle more than 2 columns if necessary.:

```
replicate(2, runif(100))
```

It may almost be benchmarking time.

Answer (score -1):

To give an overview of this thread, first of all I will show the speeds associated with the several methods used (so you can draw your own conclusion about which is the best), then I will show you how you could use a function; i.e. the way you intended your function probably.

```
n <- 1000000

> system.time(cbind(runif(n, -1, 1), runif(n, -1, 1)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.28    0.03    0.31 
> system.time(matrix(runif(2*n, min = -1, max = 1), ncol = 2))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.32    0.00    0.33 
> system.time(replicate(2, runif(n, -1, 1)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.26    0.02    0.35
```

Here is the function, and the time benchmark:

```
getPoints <- function (N) {
  pointMatrix <- matrix(1, nrow = 1000000, ncol = 2) 
  for (i in 1:N) {
    pointMatrix[i, ] <- runif(2, -1, 1) # it needs to run for all columns
  }
}

> system.time(getPoints(n))
   user  system elapsed 
  17.59    0.04   19.94 
>
```

Comment: If you run each method once through `system.time` and get 0.31, 0.33 and 0.35, how is that statistically significant? Then you write an obviously very inefficient function, what is the point? Each of the solutions showed so far can easily be turned into functions that will run in 0.3 sec...

Comment: But that's the result then; it doesn't matter much? I never said or would say that the 3rd way is worst than the first.

Comment: The function I wrote is just to show how the topic starter probably would have wanted to implement a function like that (so just pointing out the mistake in his code)